# ¿Cómo guardar la fecha seleccionada con Calendar React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar

estoy armando una página de reservas de viviendas, que debe tener un buscador para seleccionar las fechas de ida y vuelta.

Para esto quise usar react-calendar, pero no sé cómo hacer que desde el input, donde dice "ida y vuelta" se guarde la fecha seleccionada por el usuario. Probé de agregar "value={date}" en el input pero me da un error.

Agradezco su ayuda!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor poner el código a texto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo así, creé un componente Fecha para poder hacer pruebas y mandarlo completo:

---

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";
import "react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css";
import dayjs from "dayjs"; // ES 2015


function Fecha() {


 //Función adicional, creada para dar formato a la fecha.
    const formatDate = (date) => {
    return dayjs(date).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
  };

//Estado donde se guarda la fecha, pongo como inicial fecha actual.
  const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <div>
      {dateValue[0] && dateValue[1] > 1 && (
        <>
          <p>Ida: {formatDate(dateValue[0])}</p>
          <p>Ida: {formatDate(dateValue[1])}</p>
        </>
      )}
      <Calendar
        minDate={new Date()}
        selectRange={true}
        onChange={(value) => setDateValue(value)}
        value={dateValue}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Fecha;
```

En el estado dateValue se guarda la fecha, inicialmente se le asigna la fecha actual, para que el calendario siempre marque el día actual.
Luego se agregó la propiedad minDate en Calendar para que no se puedan marcar días anteriores a la fecha actual. También está selectRange, para poder seleccionar rangos.
En el evento onChange de Calendar se setea el estado, como son 2 fechas las agrega en un array, donde la posición 1 es ida y la posición 2 es vuelta.
Finalmente si están seteadas la fecha ida y la fecha vuelta se muestran ambas con un formato más corto usando una función que retorna la fecha formateada aplicando dayjs (pudo haber sido cualquier librería, como moment o date-fns).

**Lo importante es:**

```
onChange={(value) => setDateValue(value)}
```

Al cambiar el valor en el calendario, se setea el estado dateValue en este caso, luego se puede acceder a el para lo que se necesite.

---

**value** es un nombre de parámetro podría cualquiera, ej:

```
onChange={(valorDelCaldario) => setDateValue(valorDelCalendario)}
```

**dateValue** es el nombre asignado al estado, también podría haber sido cualquiera, se usó value para evitar que sea confuso con el value del onChange.

Link a documentación de dayjs.
https://day.js.org/en/

Comment: Muchas gracias! Fue esclarecedor. ¿No necesitaría un input si esa fecha la necesito dentro de un form?

Comment: En principio no necesitarías el Input, me alegra mucho que te ayude a esclarecer!!